# Отсутствует VKScope.MARKET в Android SDK Vk

Tags: java, android, vkontakte-api, вконтакте

Мне нужно выполнить market.get, для этого надо разрешение market (VKScope.MARKET), но в android sdk я его не нашёл. [image: scope]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Надо писать так:

```
private String[] scope = new String[] {VKScope.WALL, VKScope.GROUPS, VKScope.PHOTOS, "market"};
```